# Simplifying this factorial function

Tags: python, recursion

```
def factorial(t,n):
    if n == 1 : return t

    else: x = (t * (n-1))

    n = n-1

    return factorial(x,n)



print factorial(6,6)
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to just stick to requiring one parameter input while keeping the program small. I also want the function to remain recursive (trying to work on my recursive thinking).

If you have any other cooler simplifications or other fancy methods, please show it off.

Comment: Probably the easiest/best thing to do is not write this as a recursive function but as a loop.  Recognising when not to write recursion is an important concept.

Comment: Especially in Python where recursion is not really optimised.

Comment: how about a simple decrementing for loop?

Comment: Use an internal function inside factorial to do the real work, and use the wrapper function to pass in what you need. This is what I do in Haskell if I need to pretty-up explicit recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to do it recursively, you can do it dynamically:

```
from functools import wraps

def memo(f):
    """Memoizing decorator for dynamic programming."""
    @wraps(f)
    def func(*args):
        if args not in func.cache:
            func.cache[args] = f(*args)
        return func.cache[args]
    func.cache = {}
    return func

@memo
def factorial(num):
    """Recursively calculate num!."""
    if num < 0:
        raise ValueError("Negative numbers have no factorial.")
    elif num == 0:
        return 1
    return num * factorial(num-1)
```

*([`@wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), also a decorator, is just there to keep the docstring from the wrapped function in the wrapping function.)*

This will store previous results (trading space for speed) and use them in future calculations:

```
>>> factorial(4)
24
>>> factorial.cache
{(2,): 2, (0,): 1, (3,): 6, (1,): 1, (4,): 24}
```

Now if you call `factorial(5)`, it will look up `factorial(4)` from the `cache` rather than repeating the calculation. You can see this process in the traceback for a negative argument:

```
>>> factorial(-1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    factorial(-1) # call to factorial 
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 6, in func # actually calls wrapping function
    func.cache[args] = f(*args) # not in cache, so ...
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 5, in factorial # ... wrapped function gets called
    raise ValueError("Negative numbers have no factorial.") # error raised from wrapped function
ValueError: Negative numbers have no factorial.
```

*(Note that the exception interrupts the assignment to `func.cache`, so this **won't** get cached!)*

---

Bonus code golf-y iterative version:

```
from operator import mul

def factorial(num):
    """Iteratively calculate num!."""
    return reduce(mul, xrange(1, num+1)) if num else 1
```

*(This will `TypeError` on negative inputs.)*

Comment: Glad someone mentioned caching. It drastically accelerates it once it warms up. The highest factorial that can fit in a `double` is 170!, which results in 7.257415615×10³⁰⁶.

Comment: @DougGale note that these functions will return a `long` for inputs above `12`, which has [unlimited precision](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9860611/3001761), not a `float` (according to `sys.float_info`, the largest float on my installation is `1.7976931348623157e+308`).

Comment: jon, thanks for introducing the caching 'trick' to me, it looks super useful.

Answer (score 8):

First, if `n == 1`the method returns, so there is no need for the `else`.

Let us see what 6! would result in: 6 * 5! which is just 6 * 5 * 4! and so on.

Now we see a patter: n! = n * (n-1)!

Keeping this in mind we can refactor the given method to only take one parameter **and** to be recursive.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n < 0 :
        raise ValueError("Negative values are not allowed.")
    if n == 0 : return 1

    return n * factorial(n-1)

print factorial(6)
```

As [James Snell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/21492/james-snell) stated correctly in his comment, we can replace the `n == 1` check with a `n <= 2` check if we assume **n >= 1**.

As [jonrsharpe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32391/jonrsharpe) stated correctly in his comment, `0!` should return `1` and also negative numbers don't have a factorial.

As [Simon André Forsberg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-andr%c3%a9-forsberg) stated correctly in his comment, rasing an error for a negative parameter should be done.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better suited as a loop instead of recursion.

Also your function isn't truly an n-factorial function, it is a scalar multiplied by an n-factorial!

Here is a while loop version

```
def factorial(n):
    t = 1
    while not n == 1:
        t *= n
        n -= 1
    return t

print factorial(6)
```

You could also do this with a for loop as well:

```
def factorial(t):
    for n in range(1,t):
        t *= n
    return t
# note that the range is computed only once, so changing t is okay
# also note that range(1,t) is not t inclusive, 
# however the logic still includes t when finding the answer
print factorial(6)
```

Comment: The factorial function is commonly presented as a canonical example of exactly what kind of problems recursion can solve; so much so that many CS students learn it as their first recursive function declaration. As such, what leads you to state that this problem isn't well suited for recursion?

Comment: @Andrew Coonce Mainly due to the recursion limit. If I don't know the common input, I preferably to go with the method least likely to crash. Imagine the user writes `factorial(1500)`- this will crash on many systems for a recursive version, but work with a looping version!